# Contentful API only responding 1 locale

Tags: angular, rest, api, locale, contentful

I am using the javascript Contentful service for my Angular app. I made entries in Contentful which have two locales. However, when I try to use the service to request the entry, only one locale is sent instead of both.

```
this.client.getEntry(contentId);
```

The locales both have **Enable this locale in response** enabled. I also tried changing the locale of Angular, but this didn't seem to have any effect as well.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for someone who is wondering the same thing. You need to add locale as a key-value pair query to the request. Which looks like this:

```
this.client.getEntry(contentId, { locale: 'en-US'} );
```

Source: https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#querying--search-parameters